# Variable already declared in scope

Tags: android

I have two webViews in my app. If they press "N", I want to hide "M" and make "N" Visible. Vice versa when they press "N". In case, when I declare in case 1 and case 2, case 2 shows an error that it is already declared, but when I remove it, it says variable isn't declared. This is the code.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_naver:
                View naver = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                View mw = findViewById(R.id.webView2);
                mw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                naver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                return true;
            case R.id.action_mw:
                View naver = findViewById(R.id.webView);
                View mw = findViewById(R.id.webView2);
                naver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your view find's outside your switch statement to only do it once.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
View naver = findViewById(R.id.webView);
View mw = findViewById(R.id.webView2);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_naver:
            mw.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            naver.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_mw:
            naver.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```